# I am getting 406 when i am trying to hit a URI and find the count of number of requests in Ready API

Tags: ready-api, http-status-code-406

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2CeI.png)

I am getting 406 when i am trying to hit a URI and find the count of number of requests in Ready API.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? I suspect the 406 is a HTTP error code? But that has nothing to do with the number of requests in Ready API. You need to provide some more info. Are you trying to get this info with a Groovy Script? Then show the code, or at least explain what you are doing now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Steen, I was using a Wrong URI. It works now, Yes 406 is a HTTP error stating an Unacceptable request.